# I am really confused with the radio input in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

From the Vue guide, I saw these things:"For radio, checkbox and select options, the v-model binding values are usually static strings (or booleans for checkbox):" and

```
<!-- `picked` is a string "a" when checked -->
<input type="radio" v-model="picked" value="a">
```

But when I try to render picked in the tag , it does not work. why?

[Here's](http://codepen.io/xueyan123/pen/JWoVKe) my code.(in this case, it's one)

When I click the radio, it does not reflect in the tag span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing `data`, try:

```
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data: {
    picked: 'One'
  }
})
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpPmgp

Comment: oh, I see. I must declare the picked in data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add data as well in the vue instance:

```
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data: {
    picked: 'Two'
  }
})
```

Check this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMJQRB